# how to make openapi platform path parameters appear in interface

Tags: api-platform.com

I am not able to create a collection route containing path parameters in a route like

/api/myEntity/{var1}/{var2}

I created annotations in my entity like below

```
collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/smyEntity/{var1}/{var2}",
 *             "controller"=CustomController::class,
 *             "pagination_enabled"=false,
 *             "read"=false,
 *             "openapi_context"= {
 *                 "parameters" = {
 *                     {
 *                         "name" = "var1",
 *                         "in" = "path",
 *                         "type" = "string",
 *                     },
 *                     {
 *                         "name" = "var2",
 *                         "in" = "path",
 *                         "type" = "string"
 *                     }
 *                 }
 *             }
 *         }
```

I have create my custom controller but the paths parameters do not appear in api admin interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for v2.5.9 but not since 2.6.0

i will stick to 2.5.9 for now

Comment: i'm struggling with this too

Comment: v2.6.2 fixes this problem