# Replace "id" parameter with custom parameter in openapi_context (Swagger) - api-platform

Tags: swagger, openapi, api-platform.com

I have my custom operation for an entity, it uses `PUT` method, i ould like to document the parameter in my swagger (OpenApi) documentation.

This is the definition

```php
/*
 * itemOperations={
 *                  "get",
 *                  "patch",
 *                  "put",
 *                  "delete",
 *                  "activate"={
 *                      "method"="PUT",
 *                      "path"="/user/{token}/activate",
 *                      "requirements"={"token"="^\w{32}$"},
 *                      "controller"=ActivateUser::class,
 *                      "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *                      "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"user:activation"}},
 *                      "read"=false,
 *                      "validation_groups"={"Activate"},
 *                      "openapi_context"={
 *                          "summary"="Attiva un utente tramite token dopo la registrazione.",
 *                          "description"="Cambia lo stato dell'utente in 'attivo' permettendo così il login.",
 *                          "parameters"={
 *                              {
 *                                "in"="path",
 *                                "name"="token",
 *                                "required"=true,
 *                                "type"="string",
 *                                "description"="Il token generato al momento della registrazione."
 *                              }
 *                          }
 *                      }
 *                  },
 *              },
*/
```

The part interested is the `"openapi_context"` key then `"parameters"`.
This description doesn't change anything about parameters definitions, the ID requirement still remains and there's no token description (i read the documentation [here for path parameters in open api context](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#path-parameters)

[image: my actual result]

Where am i wrong? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888446/how-to-make-openapi-platform-path-parameters-appear-in-interface

Comment: Fixed (for me) with new release : https://github.com/api-platform/core/releases/tag/v2.6.2

Comment: @Gaëtan i can now document the `token` field bu i can't remove the `id`... do you know how to do it?

Comment: @JackSkeletron, were you able to get rid of the "id" parameter ?